# Hoy can I plot a group by boxplot in pandas dropping unused categories?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

Just to have the long story short. How can I plot a grouped boxplot from a category column in pandas and show only the present categories in the subset instead all posible categories.
[image]

**[reproducible example]**

I have a pandas dataframe with a factor column, and I want to plot a boxplot. If I plot by the factor is OK. If I do a subset and plot the boxplots by the factor, also is OK and only factors present in the subset are plotted. But if I have set the column as category, then all categories are ploted in the boxplot even if they are not present.

### - Create the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = ['A']*150 + ['B']*150 + ['C']*150 + ['D']*150 + ['E']*150 + ['F']*150
y = np.random.randn(900)
z = ['X']*450 + ['Y']*450
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letter':x, 'N':y, 'type':z})
print(df.head())
print(df.tail())
```

### - Plot by factor

```
df.boxplot(by='Letter')
```

[image]

### - Plot a subset (only categories in the subset are ploted but sorted alphabetically not in the wanted order)

```
df[df['type']=='X'].boxplot(by='Letter')
```

[image]

### - Convert the factor to a category and plot the subset in order to have the set ordered: All categories are plotted even if they are missing from the subset. The good part is that they are in "wanted_sort_order"

```
df['Letter2'] = df['Letter'].copy()
df['Letter2'] = df['Letter2'].astype('category')
# set a category in order to sort the factor in specific order
df['Letter2'].cat.set_categories(df['Letter2'].drop_duplicates().tolist()[::-1], inplace=True)
df[df['type']=='X'].boxplot(by='Letter2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After creating the DataFrame (first code block), try the following:

```
df['Letter2'] = pd.Categorical(df['Letter'], list('BAC'))
df[df['type']=='X'].boxplot(by='Letter2')
```

Result:

[image]

What `pd.Categorical` is doing is just simply setting as `NaN` whatever isn't in the your category list (second parameter) and `.boxplot()` naturally just ignores that and plots only the categories you are looking for.

Comment: That is very useful, thanks, but this mean that I need to capture the current categories present in the data to pass them to the second parameter (list unique elements of the column). I have found that a similar effect can be obtained with `df['Letter2'] = df['Letter2'].cat.remove_unused_categories()`